# Plot with exact same Y axis on both sides for better readability

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to create a line plot and I want to have Y axis on both left and right side.
The axes are not different. They represent same entity and have same scale and not something which requires `plotyy`.
Basically, I just want to have exact same Y axis on both sides for better readability.

PS: I am compounding multiple plots using `hold all`

How do I get Y axis on both sides?

`plotyy` is not what I want. It is used when we want to plot 2 quantities with different Y axis ranges on the same plot. That's not the case with me.

My code:

```
hold all;
plot(x,y1); %yn's use same scale and represent same physical quantity e.g. velocity.
<calculate y2>
plot(x,y2);
<calculate y3>
plot(x,y3);
.
.
hold off;
```

Comment: I assume you have a question? And that you have tried something? Those are really two things we expect here... Ask a question, and show what you tried. Can't you just do `plotyy(x,y,x,y)`? It's not efficient, but it should work...

Comment: I would create two yaxis with plotyy with some dummy data and change y axis properties on the left and right afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the command that partially does what I wanted to do

```
box on;
```

It does not give axes numbers on north sides but still gives scale which is quite helpful.